# VS C# chart несколько несвязанных линии c типом SeriesChartType.Spline

Tags: c#, диаграммы

Имеется один chart на форме, нужно начертить на нём несколько линии c ChartType = spline, таким образом что бы конец одного сплайна не соединялся с началом следующего как на скриншоте, подскажите что делать уже кучу времени потерял из-за этой фиговины

```
                   for (i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(discret); i++)
                {
                    NewSpline(myChart, k, msPoint[k], Convert.ToInt32(i));
                    k++;
                    msPoint[k] = new Series("Sinus_discret" + k);
                    msPoint[k].BorderWidth = 4;
                    msPoint[k].Color = Color.Blue;
                    msPoint[k].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                    msPoint[k].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
                    msPoint[k].ChartArea = "Math functions";
                    msPoint[k].Points.AddXY(i + 1, 0);
                    msPoint[k].Points.AddXY(i + 1, 100 / (i + 1));
                    myChart.Series.Add(msPoint[k]);
                    k++;
                }
                //MessageBox.Show(s);
                break;

    private static void NewSpline(Chart myChart, int k, Series msPoint, double c)
    {
        msPoint = new Series("Sinus_discret" + k);
        msPoint.Color = Color.Blue;
        msPoint.BorderWidth = 4;
        msPoint.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
        msPoint.ChartArea = "Math functions";
        for (double x = 0.0+c; x < 1.0+c; x += 0.1)
        {
            //double z = x + c;
            msPoint.Points.AddXY(x, Math.Round(100 / x * Math.Round(Math.Ceiling(x) - x, 1), 1));
        }
        myChart.Series.Add(msPoint);
    }
```

вот что получается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а хочется так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]